# Recursive listing of sd card files

Tags: recursion

I'm working on a MP3 player and I want to list all files on the SD card.

I have found this code on internet :

```cpp
void displaySdCardContent(FileItem& item, int numTabs) {
  for (int i = 0; i < numTabs; i++) {
    Serial.print('\t');
  }
  if (item.isDir) {
    Serial.println(item.name);
    for (FileItem fileElement : item.elements) {
      displaySdCardContent(fileElement, numTabs + 1);
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println(item.name);
  }
}

void displaySdCardContent(FileItem& item, int numTabs) {
  for (int i = 0; i < numTabs; i++) {
    Serial.print("...");
  }
  if (item.isDir) {
    Serial.println(item.name);
    for (FileItem& fileElement : item.elements) {
      displaySdCardContent(fileElement, numTabs + 1);
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println(item.name);
  }
}
```

It lists all the files but I can display only the first level directory. Here is my full code.

```cpp
#define pushButton_pin   32
// Include required libraries
#include "Audio.h"
#include "SD.h"
#include "FS.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include <TFT_eSPI.h> 
#include <SPI.h>

// microSD Card Reader connections
#define SD_CS          5
#define SPI_MOSI      21 
#define SPI_MISO      19
#define SPI_SCK       18
 
// I2S Connections
#define I2S_DOUT      22
#define I2S_BCLK      26
#define I2S_LRC       25
 
 // Create Audio object
Audio audio;

TFT_eSPI tft = TFT_eSPI();  
//digitalWrite(TFT_BL, 1);

int maxIndex;
uint32_t Freq = 0;
int Val;
String Btn, SongName;
String Status = "Idle";
bool state = true;
bool Current_State = state;
int Current_Millis;
int Previous_Millis;
int Debounce = 175;
int Xindex = 0;
int Yindex = 0;

const uint8_t maxFileNameSize = 50;
struct FileItem {
  bool isDir;
  char name[maxFileNameSize + 1];
  FileItem* upDir;
  std::vector<FileItem> elements;
};

File dir;
String CurrDir;
String NextDir;
String Song;
String Liste[50];


void setup() {
  pinMode(pushButton_pin, INPUT);
  setCpuFrequencyMhz(160);
  tft.init();
  tft.setRotation(3);
  tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLACK);
  tft.setTextWrap(false);
        
  // Set microSD Card CS as OUTPUT and set HIGH
  pinMode(SD_CS, OUTPUT);      
  digitalWrite(SD_CS, HIGH); 
    
  // Initialize SPI bus for microSD Card
  SPI.begin(SPI_SCK, SPI_MISO, SPI_MOSI);
    
  // Start Serial Port
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Start microSD Card
  if (!SD.begin(SD_CS))
  {
    Serial.println("Error accessing microSD card!");
    while(true); 
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");
  Serial.println("Creating structure of files");
  File root = SD.open("/");
  FileItem rootItem;
  if (strlen(root.name()) != 0)
    strncpy(rootItem.name, root.name(), maxFileNameSize);
  else
    strncpy(rootItem.name, "/", maxFileNameSize);
  rootItem.name[maxFileNameSize] = '\0';
  rootItem.isDir = true;
  readSdCard(root, rootItem);
  //Fin du listing

  Serial.println ("----Disp----");
  displaySdCardContent(rootItem, 0);
}

void readSdCard(File dir, FileItem& parentItem) {
  while (true) {
    File entry = dir.openNextFile();
    if (!entry) {
      break;  // no more files
    }
    FileItem item;
    item.isDir = entry.isDirectory();
    strncpy(item.name,  entry.name(), maxFileNameSize); // https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/
    item.name[maxFileNameSize] = '\0'; 
    parentItem.elements.push_back(item);
    Serial.printf("Add %s to %s\n", item.name, parentItem.name);
    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
      readSdCard(entry, item);
    }
  }
}

void displaySdCardContent(FileItem& item, int numTabs) {
  for (int i = 0; i < numTabs; i++) {
    Serial.print("...");
  }
  if (item.isDir) {
    Serial.println(item.name);
    for (FileItem& fileElement : item.elements) {
      displaySdCardContent(fileElement, numTabs + 1);
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println(item.name);
  }
}
```

I have tried this to access the second level directories :

```c
  FileItem* subFolder = &rootItem.elements.at(0);
  Serial.println ("----Disp----");
  FileItem _subFolder= *subFolder;
  
  displaySdCardContent(_subFolder, 0);
```

But it doesn't work ...

Here is what I get with the serial monitor :

```
23:36:23.419 -> Add 11-Avalanche.mp3 to War Eternal
23:36:23.419 -> Add 12-Down To Nothing.mp3 to War Eternal
23:36:23.419 -> Add 13-Not Long For This World.mp3 to War Eternal
23:36:23.451 -> Add folder.jpg to War Eternal
23:36:23.451 -> Add Will To Power to Arch Enemy
23:36:23.483 -> Add 01-Set Flame To The Night.mp3 to Will To Power
23:36:23.483 -> Add 02-The Race.mp3 to Will To Power
23:36:23.515 -> Add 03-Blood In The Water.mp3 to Will To Power
23:36:23.515 -> Add 04-The World Is Yours.mp3 to Will To Power
23:36:23.515 -> Add 05-The Eagle Flies Alone.mp3 to Will To Power
23:36:23.547 -> Add 06-Reason To Believe.mp3 to Will To Power
23:36:23.547 -> Add 07-Murder Scene.mp3 to Will To Power
23:36:23.579 -> Add 08-First Day In Hell.mp3 to Will To Power
23:36:23.579 -> Add 09-Saturnine.mp3 to Will To Power
23:36:23.612 -> Add 10-Dreams Of Retribution.mp3 to Will To Power
23:36:23.643 -> Add 11-My Shadow And I.mp3 to Will To Power
23:36:23.643 -> Add 12-A Fight I Must Win.mp3 to Will To Power
23:36:23.675 -> Add folder.jpg to Will To Power
23:36:23.675 -> ----Disp----
23:36:23.675 -> Arch Enemy
```

Edit :
Attributes item i can print  in `displaySdCardContent()`

```
14:58:54.763 -> ----Disp----
14:58:54.763 -> name : Arch Enemy
14:58:54.763 -> IsDir : 1
```

Debug in `ReadsdCard`

```
⸮⸮item name : 07. [Through The Eyes Of A Raven].mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : CD1 - Khaos Legions
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :7
Add 07. [Through The Eyes Of A Raven].mp3 to CD1 - Khaos Legions
item name : 08. [Cruelty Without Beauty].mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : CD1 - Khaos Legions
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :8
Add 08. [Cruelty Without Beauty].mp3 to CD1 - Khaos Legions
item name : 09. [We Are A Godless Entity].mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : CD1 - Khaos Legions
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :9
Add 09. [We Are A Godless Entity].mp3 to CD1 - Khaos Legions
item name : 10. [Cult Of Chaos].mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : CD1 - Khaos Legions
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :10
Add 10. [Cult Of Chaos].mp3 to CD1 - Khaos Legions
item name : 11. [Thorns In My Flesh].mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : CD1 - Khaos Legions
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :11
Add 11. [Thorns In My Flesh].mp3 to CD1 - Khaos Legions
item name : 12. [Turn To Dust].mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : CD1 - Khaos Legions
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :12
Add 12. [Turn To Dust].mp3 to CD1 - Khaos Legions
item name : 13. [Vengeance Is Mine].mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : CD1 - Khaos Legions
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :13
Add 13. [Vengeance Is Mine].mp3 to CD1 - Khaos Legions
item name : 14. [Secrets].mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : CD1 - Khaos Legions
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :14
Add 14. [Secrets].mp3 to CD1 - Khaos Legions
item name : CD2 - Kovered In Khaos
item IsDir : 1
item size :0
parent item name : 2011 - Khaos Legions (2xCD, Ltd)
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :2
Add CD2 - Kovered In Khaos to 2011 - Khaos Legions (2xCD, Ltd)
item name : 01. [Warning].mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : CD2 - Kovered In Khaos
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :1
Add 01. [Warning].mp3 to CD2 - Kovered In Khaos
item name : 02. [Wings Of Tomorrow].mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : CD2 - Kovered In Khaos
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :2
Add 02. [Wings Of Tomorrow].mp3 to CD2 - Kovered In Khaos
item name : 03. [The Oath].mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : CD2 - Kovered In Khaos
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :3
Add 03. [The Oath].mp3 to CD2 - Kovered In Khaos
item name : 04. [The Book Of Heavy Metal].mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : CD2 - Kovered In Khaos
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :4
Add 04. [The Book Of Heavy Metal].mp3 to CD2 - Kovered In Khaos
item name : Folder.jpg
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : 2011 - Khaos Legions (2xCD, Ltd)
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :3
Add Folder.jpg to 2011 - Khaos Legions (2xCD, Ltd)
item name : War Eternal
item IsDir : 1
item size :0
parent item name : Arch Enemy
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :4
Add War Eternal to Arch Enemy
item name : 01-Tempore Nihil Sanat (Prelude in F minor).mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : War Eternal
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :1
Add 01-Tempore Nihil Sanat (Prelude in F minor).mp3 to War Eternal
item name : 02-Never Forgive, Never Forget.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : War Eternal
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :2
Add 02-Never Forgive, Never Forget.mp3 to War Eternal
item name : 03-War Eternal.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : War Eternal
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :3
Add 03-War Eternal.mp3 to War Eternal
item name : 04-As The Pages Burn.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : War Eternal
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :4
Add 04-As The Pages Burn.mp3 to War Eternal
item name : 05-No More Regrets.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : War Eternal
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :5
Add 05-No More Regrets.mp3 to War Eternal
item name : 06-You Will Know My Name.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : War Eternal
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :6
Add 06-You Will Know My Name.mp3 to War Eternal
item name : 07-Graveyard Of Dreams.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : War Eternal
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :7
Add 07-Graveyard Of Dreams.mp3 to War Eternal
item name : 08-Stolen Life.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : War Eternal
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :8
Add 08-Stolen Life.mp3 to War Eternal
item name : 09-Time Is Black.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : War Eternal
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :9
Add 09-Time Is Black.mp3 to War Eternal
item name : 10-On And On.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : War Eternal
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :10
Add 10-On And On.mp3 to War Eternal
item name : 11-Avalanche.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : War Eternal
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :11
Add 11-Avalanche.mp3 to War Eternal
item name : 12-Down To Nothing.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : War Eternal
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :12
Add 12-Down To Nothing.mp3 to War Eternal
item name : 13-Not Long For This World.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : War Eternal
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :13
Add 13-Not Long For This World.mp3 to War Eternal
item name : folder.jpg
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : War Eternal
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :14
Add folder.jpg to War Eternal
item name : Will To Power
item IsDir : 1
item size :0
parent item name : Arch Enemy
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :5
Add Will To Power to Arch Enemy
item name : 01-Set Flame To The Night.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : Will To Power
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :1
Add 01-Set Flame To The Night.mp3 to Will To Power
item name : 02-The Race.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : Will To Power
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :2
Add 02-The Race.mp3 to Will To Power
item name : 03-Blood In The Water.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : Will To Power
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :3
Add 03-Blood In The Water.mp3 to Will To Power
item name : 04-The World Is Yours.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : Will To Power
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :4
Add 04-The World Is Yours.mp3 to Will To Power
item name : 05-The Eagle Flies Alone.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : Will To Power
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :5
Add 05-The Eagle Flies Alone.mp3 to Will To Power
item name : 06-Reason To Believe.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : Will To Power
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :6
Add 06-Reason To Believe.mp3 to Will To Power
item name : 07-Murder Scene.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : Will To Power
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :7
Add 07-Murder Scene.mp3 to Will To Power
item name : 08-First Day In Hell.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : Will To Power
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :8
Add 08-First Day In Hell.mp3 to Will To Power
item name : 09-Saturnine.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : Will To Power
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :9
Add 09-Saturnine.mp3 to Will To Power
item name : 10-Dreams Of Retribution.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : Will To Power
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :10
Add 10-Dreams Of Retribution.mp3 to Will To Power
item name : 11-My Shadow And I.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : Will To Power
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :11
Add 11-My Shadow And I.mp3 to Will To Power
item name : 12-A Fight I Must Win.mp3
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : Will To Power
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :12
Add 12-A Fight I Must Win.mp3 to Will To Power
item name : folder.jpg
item IsDir : 0
item size :0
parent item name : Will To Power
parent item IsDir : 1
Parent item size :13
Add folder.jpg to Will To Power
----end of listing ----
rootItem.element[0] name : Arch Enemy
rootItem.element[0] IsDir : 1
rootItem.element[0] size :0
```

Comment: i am trying to access sub directories, but "it doesn't work". The original code with displaySdCardContent(rootItem,0); display the first level, and my test also display the only first level

Comment: OT: You set no `upDir` value in your items. However, you don't use it.

Comment: I see no apparent error on a first glance, and I don't have the hardware to reproduce. Please [edit] your question with the results of debugging output of `item`'s attributes in `displaySdCardContent()`. If this looks fishy, do the same while building the tree of `item`s in `readSdCard()`.

Comment: the debugging output is already in my question . Before the "23:36:23.675 -> ----Disp----" it's the output while building the tree, and after is the output of '''displaySdCardContent().

Comment: Please read closer: I'd like to see **all attributes** of each `item` given to `displaySdCardContent()`.

Comment: i can only acces items in root, and there is one folder. I can just print `name` and `isDir`. `upDir` is an item and `Elements` a vector items, i can't print  it.

Comment: Thanks. As `isDir` is 1, `item.elements` _should_ be iterated. Apparently it is not, so please print `item.elements.size()`. And so on, you will want to "single-step" through the data with multiple prints.

Comment: item.elements.size return 0  ... o_O? 
`20:20:47.622 -> name : Arch Enemy
20:20:47.622 -> IsDir : 1
20:20:47.622 -> size :0`

Comment: The next step is logical: Add debug prints to `readSdCard()` for each completed `item` before appending it, and to `setup()` for `rootItem.elements[0]`.

Comment: i have edited the question with `readSdCard()` debug. I don't know why i can't get the begining but what i understand, each item have a size equal to 0, but each time it's add to the parent directory, parentdirectory size rise by 1 and when it change the directory, parent item size restart to 0.

Comment: Thanks for the debug log! It looks as if the `readSdCard()` works like expected and populates your tree. There must be something else. Unfortunately I need some sleep now, I'll get back in some hours.

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to do; you appear to be building a tree structure on the stack by recursively navigating the SD file structure. You are clearly expecting that tree structure to still exist intact after the recursively called function's final invocation returns so you can then navigate that tree structure with another recursive function. Are you sure that the tree will exist at the you try to navigate it ?

Comment: In the meantime you've got an answer and maybe that solves it but I set up a quick Wokwi ESP32 simulation including a sample file structure but using the LittleFS instead of the SD filesystem so that it can be experimented with online. The core is similar to your original simple recursive scan rather that your two pass solution. It based on a general "randomnerd" tutorial and that appears to work. https://wokwi.com/projects/383917656227391489

Comment: thank you, yes the answer solve my problem, but i keep your code, just in case ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is hard to see, but it is essentially in this original sequence (irrelevant statements omitted):

```cpp
    FileItem item;
    // ...
    parentItem.elements.push_back(item);
    // ...
      readSdCard(entry, item);
    }
```

The method `push_back()` **copies** the `item` to `elements`. Since at that moment `item` has no elements, the copy also has none. Later modifications of `item` do not change the copy.

There are multiple alternatives to correct.

**1. Recurse first, then push:**

```cpp
    FileItem item;
    // ...
      readSdCard(entry, item);
    }
    // ...
    parentItem.elements.push_back(item);
```

This way `item`'s `elements` vector collect its entries before the `push_back()`.

However, the order of debug messages changes.

**2. Recurse with the copy:**

```cpp
    FileItem item;
    // ...
    parentItem.elements.push_back(item);
    // ...
      readSdCard(entry, parentItem.elements.back());
    }
```

In this case `readSdCard()` uses the copy of `item` in `parentItem`'s `elements` to collect the entries.

Comment: Thank you so much !! it seems to work, i have quickly try to navigate in tree and `Serial.println(rootItem.elements[0].elements.at(1).elements[1].name);` return an mp3 file ! Now i have to deal with this tree to print it on my screen but the hardest thing is done :) thank you again !